# get only numeric columns in python blaze object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, blaze

I have a `blaze` data object like this

```
import blaze as bz

bdata = bz.Data([(1, 'Alice', 100.9),
           (2, 'Bob', 200.6),
           (3, 'Charlie', 300.45),
           (5, 'Edith', 400)],
          fields=['id', 'name', 'amount'])
bdata

  | id | name   | amount
--------------------------
0 | 1  | Alice  | 100.90
1 | 2  | Bob    | 200.60
2 | 3  | Charlie| 300.45
3 | 5  | Edith  | 400.00
```

I want to get only those column names which have `numeric datatypes`.For example here only `id` and `amount` has numeric values.

I am able to get the column types using `dshape` as follows

```
bdata.dshape
dshape("4 * {id: int64, name: string, amount: float64}")
```

But not sure how to utilize this properly. I know how to do the same thing in `pandas` using `_get_numeric_data()` function. Looking for a similar function or code in `blaze`

Answer (score 0):

There could be an easier way. Here's one way to accomplish it

```
In [75]:
def get_numeric_cols(dshape):
    shape = dshape.parameters[-1].dict
    cols = []
    for k in shape:
        type = str(shape[k])
        if type.startswith("int") or type.startswith("float"):
            cols.append(k)
    return cols

In [76]: get_numeric_cols(bdata.dshape)
Out[76]: ['amount', 'id']
```

Basically, look for `int*` or `float*` types?